# Grouping data with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Right now I have some data

```
year,0-19 years,20-39 years,40-59 years,60-79 years,80-99 years,100 years+
2015,100,100,100,100,100,100
2016,99.13845985,100.6510799,100.3768131,101.6514052,102.1909752,103.1311155
2017,98.47752007,101.3914524,100.315877,103.2268878,104.8870115,110.665362
2018,97.88886938,102.1734045,100.1076517,104.618223,108.1048883,113.7964775
2019,97.48903691,102.7318398,99.88340414,105.934158,111.6868789,118.1996086
2020,97.24146004,103.3374176,99.56154293,107.1695557,115.2344717,122.407045
```

I am plotting my data with

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    width=\textwidth,
    height=0.5\textwidth,
    xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=, rotate=45},
]

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{index.dat}{\loadedtable}

\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0-19 years,20-39 years,40-59 years,60-79 years,80-99 years,100 years+}{
    \addplot table [x=year, y=#1, col sep=comma] {\loadedtable};
    \addlegendentry{#1}
}

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

But in this example, I have already made the sums to make the 20 years groups (0-19, 20-39, etc.).

If I had the data as

```
year,1 year,2 year,3 year,4 year,[...]
2015,3,4,1,5,[...]
2016,2,1,5,9,[...]
[...]
```

is it possible to let `pgfplots` make the grouping/sums, so I just specify 1-19, 20-39, etc?

Comment: yes. Have a look at the `statistics` library and the `hist` handler. Because of the short data file I cannot provide a full answer ...

Comment: But I think you have to transpose your data file, so make the rows columns and the columns rows. This could be done with the `pgfplotstable` table, too.

Comment: Did my comments help you to solve your problem or do you need further assistance?